# What layout to use to produce a data entry form in android

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best layout to use tp produce a data entry form like this one in android:
[image: entry form]

Should I use a vertical linear layout,, with a horizental layout for each of the items? or a relative layout. I can't use a table layout because each text entry might have it's own width.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As main layout, you can use a linear layout vertical, and for each row, a linear layout horizontal, setting width to fill_parent.
For the 4 first rows (data form container), when setting width, use "0 dip" for width and set a proportion to layout_weight as you need, keep the same value for the 3 next row in order to keep the alignement. Dont forget to set gravity right fo first column

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:paddingLeft="50dip"
    android:paddingRight="50dip"> 

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="label"
    android:gravity="right"/>

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:hint="value"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"/>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Do so, for last row with 0.5 proportion for each column.

Think, that helped you...

Answer (score 1):

relative layout will be useful and use padding attribute to obtain the UI as image

Answer (score 0):

As per my view you can pick linear layout it will be easy to handle

one Linear layout with vertical orientation
and 5 linear layouts with horizontal orientation

Comment: Which gives better performance, Linear Layout or Relative layout

Comment: have seen this documentation , will help you http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html